# Placing wsp file in GAC folder-Sharepoint Custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint, wsp

I wrote a webpart in C# and build it successfully in Visual Studio 2008. I have SP 2007 in my local machine.

I cannot do debugbing. I have to place the wsp file in Gac so that I can debug it.

How can I place it in C;\Windows\Assembly\GAC_MSIL as I cannot manully browse into that loaction.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `.pdb` file to the GAC folder where the `.dll` file is located, not the entire `.wsp` package. Do not forget `iisreset` afterwards.

To browse the `c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\` folder use one of these [5 tricks](http://blog.mediawhole.com/2010/09/exposing-global-assembly-cache.html). There is also a 6<sup>th</sup> way - Total Commander treats GAC like any other folder.